# I get a segmentation fault when i run this

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

so I want to create an address book program and I have this following code :

```
#define MAX_VALUE_FOR_ARRAYS 1000

int i = 0 ;
int answer = 0 ;
int number_of_people = 0 ;

FILE* address_book = NULL ;

address_book = fopen("addressBook.txt", "w")  ;

typedef struct People People ;

struct People
{
    char f_name[MAX_VALUE_FOR_ARRAYS]
};

People *persons = NULL ;

printf("A D D R R E S S  B O O K \n\n\n") ;

printf("1. Add a new contact \n") ;
printf("2. View all contacts \n") ;
printf("\nMake your choice : ") ;

while (answer < 1 || answer > 2)
{
    printf("\nWrong input, try again ! : ") ;
    scanf("%d", &answer) ;
}

if (answer == 1)
{
    printf("How many contacts do you want to add ? : ") ;
    scanf("%d", &number_of_people) ;

    persons = malloc(number_of_people * sizeof(char*) ) ;

    if (persons == NULL)
    {
        printf("\nMemory allocation failed !") ;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < number_of_people; i++)
    {
        printf("Person %d ", (i+1)) ;
        printf("Enter the first name : ") ;
        scanf("%s", &persons[i].f_name) ;

        if (address_book == NULL)
        {
        printf("\nFailed to open file ! ") ;
        }

    fputs(persons[i].f_name, address_book) ;
    fputc('\n', address_book) ;

    }
}
```

My problem is that the program doesn't work ( i get a segmentation fault) whenever the variable "number_of_people" is greater than 3, in other cases ( number_of_people < 3) it works properly. I don't know what's going wrong, help please.

Comment: Does `#define MAX_VALUE_FOR_ARRAYS` really have nothing after it? If so, that's your problem. You need to provide a value for how much memory to reserve for the name to be copied into.

Comment: `malloc(number_of_people * sizeof(char*) )` -> `malloc(number_of_people * sizeof(struct People) )`.

Comment: Retired Ninja, it haas the value "1000" after it, my bad, i forgot to write it

Comment: John, I tried it, it's working now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is an error in the malloc call, you are allocating the wrong size of pointer. Try this way:

```
    #define MAX_VALUE_FOR_ARRAYS 1000
    int i = 0 ;
    int answer = 0 ;
    int number_of_people = 0 ;

    FILE* address_book = NULL ;

    address_book = fopen("addressBook.txt", "w")  ;

    typedef struct People People ;

    struct People
    {
        char f_name[MAX_VALUE_FOR_ARRAYS]
    };

    People *persons = NULL ;

    printf("A D D R R E S S  B O O K \n\n\n") ;

    printf("1. Add a new contact \n") ;
    printf("2. View all contacts \n") ;
    printf("\nMake your choice : ") ;


    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%d", &answer) ;
        if ( (answer < 1) || (answer > 2) )
          printf("\nWrong input, try again ! : ") ;
        else
          break;
    }


    if (answer == 1)
    {
        printf("How many contacts do you want to add ? : ") ;
        scanf("%d", &number_of_people) ;

        persons = malloc(number_of_people * sizeof(People) ) ;

        if (persons == NULL)
        {
            printf("\nMemory allocation failed !") ;
        }

        for (i = 0; i < number_of_people; i++)
        {
            printf("Person %d ", (i+1)) ;
            printf("Enter the first name : ") ;
            scanf("%s", &persons[i].f_name) ;

            if (address_book == NULL)
            {
            printf("\nFailed to open file ! ") ;
            }
    fputs(persons[i].f_name, address_book) ;
    fputc('\n', address_book) ;

    }
}
```

I've also changed a little bit the while loop to show an error only if the user make a wrong selection in the first menu.

Comment: I changed the malloc call syntax, it's now working, thanks. Thanks for also making the "while loop" a little better ;)

Comment: Hi Tony, glad it helped! If you like, please accept the answer! Thank you and have a nice day!

Comment: I accepted it, thanks again and have a nice day/night too